# Thread pool when serving multiple clients with blocking methods

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server, threadpool, executorservice

I am developing a webserver in java that will provide websocket communication to its' clients. I have been proposed to use a thread pool when dealing with many clients because it is a lot more time efficient than to use one thread per client.

My question is simply, will Javas ExecutorService, newFixedThreadPool be able to handle a queue of runnable tasks with thread blocking methods being called inside of them?

In other words i guess i am wondering if this thread pool is asynchronous?

The reason i am asking is that i have tried using a newFixedThreadPool with, lets say, 2 threads. Then when i connect 3 clients to the server, i can only receive commands from the first two. But i guess i could be doing something wrong, thats why i am asking.

The runnable tasks are also in an infinite while loop (only ends when client disconnects).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on your implementation. The easiest case is having clients keeping their thread active until the disconnect (or get kicked out because of a timeout). In this case, your thread pool isn't very efficient. I'll only re-use disconnected users' threads instead of creating new one (which is good, but not really relevant).

The second case would be activating the threads only when needed (let's say when a client sends or receives a messages). In this case, you need to remember the server-side (keeping an id for example), in order to be able to sever the thread connection when they don't need them, and re-establish it when they do. In order to do that, you must keep the sockets somewhere, but unbound to any specific thread.

I actually didn't code that myself but I don't see why it would work as this is the mechanism used for websites (i.e. HTTP protocol)